# Angular 6 binding Tree Object with html element

Tags: javascript, angular, tree

I am a begginer Angular 6 Developper.

I have workout to render an tree object like an Org Chart.

The problem starts when i try do a two-way data-bind to modify the tree object when i change something in html.

There's something possible like that? I want change in front and get changes in object js automatically.

Comment: `formArray` is the key

Comment: you're right! that's what i need. thanks @JacopoSciampi

Comment: Let me know if you need an help understanding this argument, it's not that easy.